# Can Objective-C compile to C?

Tags: objective-c, c

Can I compile an Objective-C program to C?

I'm interested if this can be done so that it can be compiled with other C compilers.

I am aware that GCC can compile Objective-C.

Comment: I don't think that even C compiles to C. C typically compiles to assembler...

Comment: @DerekTomes: I've got a tool that can compile C to C.  It might be installed on your system, it's called `cat`...

Comment: @DerekTomes C normally compiles to machine code, as far as I know. That's not assembler.

Comment: @Sulthan: Most modern compilers compile C to some intermediate format (e.g., LLVM), then compile that to assembly, then assemble that to machine code. (And that's ignoring the fact that bits of your code actually end up as linker directives, not actual code, and even the actual code may be relocated or otherwise modified at runtime before it can be executed.)

Comment: Not only modern compilers,portable C compilers(even olders) compile to some IF/IL.

Comment: @pikapika: I think that you're a bit confusing... despite you can only call `gcc` program name on shell,differents compilers are called according to file extension(or a explicit language set by `-x` option).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Sure, you have a C-to-C compiler, but what about a decompiler to reverse the transformation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The tricky thing is that if you use the compiler `cat` N times, you must use the decompiler `cat` exactly N or fewer times, or more times, to get the original text back. To put it another way: with `rot13`, you must use the decoder an odd number of times iff you used the encoder an odd number of times; with `cat` you must use the decompiler a number of times iff you used the compiler a number of times.

Answer (score 12):

Sure. For example, [POC](http://users.telenet.be/stes/compiler.html) compiles Objective C to plain C code, and the recommended way to use it is to then compile that C code with gcc.

Of course the generated C is an unreadable mess, consisting mostly of calls (through generated `extern` declarations) to objc_runtime calls, so you'll need to link that runtime to your compiled code.

There's also an LLVM backend that generates C code from any frontend. So, you can plug in the `clang` Objective C frontend and the C backend and build your own ObjC-to-C compiler. The result will probably be even *more* unreadable than what POC generates.

---

Of course most people don't want to compile Objective C*, they want to compile "Objective C 4.0".** POC won't do that; only clang and llvm-gcc will (and in the future, most likely only clang). And they don't just want an Objective C runtime, they want the OS X or the iOS runtime, or at least OpenStep, which again pretty much means clang, llvm-gcc, or gcc.

---

The big question is, why do you want to do this? You will need to have an Objective C runtime to link to, and your C code will have to be compiled in a way that's ABI-compatible with the way that runtime was compiled, so… I'm not sure what you're going to gain over just compiling from ObjC to native code with gcc or clang in the first place.

---

* As in the language defined in Brad Cox's 1986 book and/or in his 1991 followup.

** Note that Apple explicitly decided *not* to call their latest revisions to the language "Objective-C 4.0"… or anything else. The last version with a name, or a real specification, was "The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language". But Apple has continued to add features, and the "unnamed feature set that came in with the LLVM 4.0 frontend for Objective-C 2.0" is a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: internally apple is calling it [`objc4`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/version.rc)

Comment: @ikinciviking: Yeah, and they initially used that name publicly, too… but somewhere in the docs, there's a statement that says that the language is explicitly not called Objective-C 4 or 4.0, and likewise for the runtime, and there was even a link there from one of their main tutorial or FAQ pages. But they didn't tell us what to call it instead. So, you still have to call it _something_, but you have to put that something in scare quotes and/or add an asterisk. (Kind of like pronouncing Prince's name while it was a symbol.)

Comment: "a language formally known as Objective-C 2": ALFKAO2

Comment: The name "objc4" for the runtime itself is unrelated to any language versioning. objc4's name is probably twenty years old, a historical remnant of version 4 of NeXT's operating system.

Comment: @GregParker: Ah, you're right. The relevant 4 seems to be Apple's internal LLVM 4.0 branch, or maybe Xcode 4.0. At any rate, since Apple has said it's _not_ called 4.0, asking why it's called 4.0 seems unlikely to ever get a good answer…

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes, but it'll be really ugly. LLVM had a C backend — i.e. it could compile to C — up to version 3.1. There have been [efforts to revive it](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2OTg) but I can't speak as to their progress. There's also a C++ backend that is better maintained but doesn't quite do the same thing.

However you'll have the obvious problem that none of the Foundation libraries will be available on your target platform. No `NSString`, no `NSArray`, etc. Once you've found a working implementation of those you'll also have found a working Objective-C compiler.

Comment: Well, you can use GNUStep's FoundationKit instead of Cocoa's Foundation, and GNUStep is pretty portable. (It's still not compatible with POC, of course… there was an ObjectKit-to-OpenStep shim framework many years ago, but I doubt that's been kept up to date.)

Comment: I didn't realize the C backend had died and been revived yet again. It hasn't caught up to Kenny yet, or even Rory, but it definitely has problems staying dead.